# Why doesn't subset sum problem contradict the Exponential time hypothesis?

Tags: time-complexity

Subset sum can be solved with dynamic programming in pseudopolynomial time O(mn) which is subexponential. And, of course, subset sum problem is NP-complete. Why doesn't that contradict the Exponential time hypothesis?

Comment: Possible duplicate. https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/71161/how-is-the-subset-sum-problem-np-complete

Comment: The dynamic programming algorithm runs in exponential time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How is the Subset Sum Problem NP-Complete?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/71161/how-is-the-subset-sum-problem-np-complete)